# Android: How to solve slow response after clicking TabWidget

Tags: android

I have four Tab at the top of my apps
The content of the fourth tab is that it will get data from sql server and then display in listview
since the amount of data retrieved is quite big, it takes 2-3 sec
The problem is that:
After I click the fourth tab, it has no response, then after 2-3sec, it displays the content
As I know it is loading the data from database, I will not continue to click
However, when users click it and no response, he may click and click and click
How to show something to user so that they know it is loading data??

Comment: use progress dialog loading.... to display

Comment: where should I put the dialog?? need to have a new thread??

Comment: can U check the below answer that I wrote. let me know if you cant fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [CrusorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html). This will display a loading circle while still making the UI active. Note that even if you're using lower versions of the android API, you can still access the CursorLoader class via the [Android Support Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html). For more information on [loaders](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html), checkout

Comment: where should I use cursor loader??As in the main.java, my code is

Comment: where should I use cursor loader??As in the main.java, my code is  tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab4")
    .setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.compass))
    .setContent(new Intent(this, map_activity.class)));
where should I use the cursor or dialog?

Comment: please look at the examples I posted above for information on how to use the cursor loader. Name, look at: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html#example

Answer (score 2):

new SomeTask(0).execute(); // write this line in your 4th tab onCreate()

```
/** Inner class for implementing progress bar before fetching data **/
    private class SomeTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> 
    {
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(yourActivityClass.this);
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {

            Dialog.setMessage("loading...");
            Dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {
            //Task for doing something 
 //   get data from sql server and then display in listview
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result)
            {

            if(result==0)
            {
//do some thing if your list completed
            }

    // after completed finished the progressbar
            Dialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
```

Comment: An async task is a little complex for such a simple need. A loader is better used in this situation.

Comment: thx Padma and Kurtis, I am trying both of your methods..  report upon done!!

Comment: @red23jordan which way U tried. can u send me the code if you used  a CrusorLoader.

Answer (score 0):

When a long-running process is started, you'll want to indicate that something is happening so the user knows to wait.  You want a progress dialog.

Here is an example:
http://www.androidpeople.com/android-progress-dialog-example